# Syntax issue with correlating multiple values from redirects

Tags: locust

I have one step that has multiple redirects and I need to call them and correlate values out of them to pass in subsequent calls.

```
@seq_task(2)

def Sign_in_with_site2_ID_btn (self):

    response = self.client.get('https://healthid.redirectedsite.com/tb/views/login.jsf?
```

relyingAppId=PRD23484&TARGET=https%3A%2F%2Flinksession.site2.com%2Fproxy%3Fredirect%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsite1.linkhealth.com%252Fapps%252Fsecure%252Fdashboards%252Fsite1-dashboard%252F'),
        jsessionid = response.cookies['JSESSIONID'],

```
def redirect1 (self):

    response = 
self.client.post(url='https://healthid.redirectedsite.com/siteminderagent/forms/login.fcc'),

            cookies = {'JSESSIONID': self.parent.res.cookies['JSESSIONID'],
                       'caData': self.parent.res2.cookies['caData'],
                       'oid_data': self.parent.res.cookies['oid_data']},
                                   catch_response = True) as self.response:
    print("jsessionid" + self.JSESSIONID)
    print("caData" + self.caData)
    print("oid_data" + self.oid_data)



class User(HttpLocust):class User(HttpLocust):
task_set = UserBehaviour
wait_time = between(5, 10)
host = "https://MainHost.linkhealth.com/#/"
```

Comment: Hi! I need more context to be able to answer your question. What are you trying to do, and what is the problem/error that you are getting? Also, your formatting was a bit mangled by stackoverflow, can you try to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Still a little new to locust. It was solved by properly formatting the function. I had it all wrong.